How to determine the cause of a linker error for a derived class
I am unable to decipher a linker error and would like to understand the issue. To provide more context: I have an interface class like below
class ModuleInterface {
    public:
    
        virtual ~ModuleInterface() = default;
    
 
        using Messages = std::unordered_set<Identifier>;
    
 
        virtual Messages getSupportedMessages() = 0;
    
     
        virtual void cancelMessage(MessageHeader messageHeader) = 0;
    
    };

I have a stubModule class as below
    class StubModule : public ModuleInterface {
    public:
    
        ~StubModule() override = default;
         /* have tried
        ~StubModule() = default;
        */
        Messages getSupportedMessages() override;
        void cancelMessage(MessageHeader messageHeader) override;
    
    };


cpp class looks like 

Messages StubModule::getSupportedMessages(){
    Messages messages;
    messages.insert(Identifier("name"));
    return messages;
}


void StubModule::cancelMessage(MessageHeader messageHeader){
    ....
}

In my main.cpp I am creating the class like this
std::shared_ptr<ModuleInterface> stubModule = std::make_shared<StubModule>();

but I am seeing an error like below
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: vtable for adk::utils::server::StubModule
>>> referenced by StubModule.h:22 (/foo/SampleServer/StubModule.h:22)
>>>               SampleServer/Main.cpp.o:(StubModule::StubModule())
>>> the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see https://lld.llvm.org/missingkeyfunction)
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
CMake Build Error

I suspect that it is something to do with the first virtual function which is the destructor in this case and I have tried the following things:
removing ~StubModule() override = default;adding StubModule() = default;, removing virtual ~ModuleInterface() = default;but then I get a different error. I have made sure I am overriding all the methods in the interface but I am not sure why I am receiving this error.
Is my understanding correct that first virtual method is the key function in this case?

Linker doesn't see definition of one or more virtual functions. Either you forgot to implement one (or more) of them or the problem is in your build system and you don't link one (or more) files.

@Yksisarvinen sorry it should have been cancelMessage, fixed the question

@Yksisarvinen actually you are right, the cpp file was somehow not getting included in build but i was just not able to make that connection from this error, thanks.
